# How to merge rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| productID | units sold | units in inventory |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 32 | NaN |
| 102 | 45 | NaN |
| 103 | 15 | NaN |
| 104 | 27 | NaN |
| 101 | NaN | 18 |
| 102 | NaN | 12 |
| 103 | NaN | 30 |
| 104 | NaN | 23 |

As you can see, the first column contains duplicates, where each instance has data in one 'data' column, but not the other 'data' column.

Is there a way to merge the rows, so the dataframe looks like this?

| productID | units sold | units in inventory |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 32 | 18 |
| 102 | 45 | 12 |
| 103 | 15 | 30 |
| 104 | 27 | 23 |

Comment: [`Groupby.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) -> `df.groupby('productID', as_index=False).first()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `groupby.first`:

```
>>> df.groupby('productID', as_index=False).first()
   productID  units sold  units in inventory
0        101        32.0                18.0
1        102        45.0                12.0
2        103        15.0                30.0
3        104        27.0                23.0
>>>
```